# sql select where all in

Tags: select, where-clause, informix

i need to make select like this:

```
Select * from father 
  where All (select age, high from sons where father.id = sons.f_id) 
          IN ( (18, 150), (19, 138))
```

Is that possible ? I always have syntax error. I use informix database.

Thanks, 
   Lukas

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM father
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM sons
                  WHERE sons.f_id = father.id
                  AND NOT ((sons.age = 18 AND sons.high = 150)
                           OR (sons.age = 19 AND sons.high = 138)))
```